# problems with an object product wooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have a problem with de product object , it takes always the last item ...

i need help realy please

```
function buttonCart() {
    global $product;


        //button si il est connecté ou non 
        if (is_user_logged_in()){
             echo '<a href='.get_permalink($product_id).'/'.$product->id.'><button class="second_content">location'.$product_id.'</button></a>';
             echo '<button class="second_content">achat</button>';

        }else{


            echo '<script>';
            echo 'var monObjet = '.json_encode($product).';';
            echo '</script>';

        echo '<a><button class="second_content">en savoir plus '. $product->get_sku().'</button></a><button i type="button" onclick="ShowModal(monObjet)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" >Open Modal</button>';
            var_dump($product);


        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

thank in advance

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum, in this case: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

Comment: the part of the code that you show is irelevant, you need to see that the product is set properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using it incorrectly. you use `$product_id`, which is not defined anywhere,i think you should use: `$product->id`.

p.s. beautify the code, it's hard to read.

Comment: the main is not de product-ID but from else

Comment: it is when i create my object who take always de same value